# Python: insert UUID value in Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to insert the UUID value into sqlite3 database as

```
INSERT INTO user (user_id,username, email) VALUES (uuid.UUID('7005d0e0-f25b-45f9-897d-bae151fddaff'),'user', 'user@gmail.com')
```

And I am storing the UUID value in the database as a custom data type 'GUID'. For this conversion, I am using sqlite3 converter as

```
sqlite3.register_converter('GUID', lambda b: uuid.UUID(bytes_le=b))
```

The problem with this query, the query execution gets failed as:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Am I missing anything? I want to store the UUID value into the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are putting Python code in the SQL expression, and you registered a handler to convert SQLite data to a Python type.

Register an adapter for the type, then insert the UID as a SQL parameter. Or pass in a literal byte sequence in the SQL query.

An adapter is as simple as:

```
sqlite3.register_adapter(uuid.UUID, lambda u: u.bytes_le)
```

and then you can use your instance as a query parameter:

```
cursor.execute('''
        INSERT INTO user (user_id, username, email) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ''', (
        uuid.UUID('7005d0e0-f25b-45f9-897d-bae151fddaff'), 'user',
        'user@gmail.com'
    ))
```

To go the other direction, getting a `uuid.UUID()` instance from a `SELECT` query, you'd either have to use the type name in the `register_converter()` call in the column definition of the table schema, or use the type name in the column name of the select; you need to tell `sqlite3` what variants you plan use in the `connect()` call (it can be both).

Demo:

```
>>> import uuid, sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
>>> sqlite3.register_adapter(uuid.UUID, lambda u: u.bytes_le)
>>> sqlite3.register_converter('GUID', lambda b: uuid.UUID(bytes_le=b))
>>> conn.execute('CREATE TABLE user (user_id GUID, username TEXT, email TEXT)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1074065e0>
>>> with conn:
...     cursor = conn.cursor()
...     cursor.execute('''
...             INSERT INTO user (user_id, username, email)
...             VALUES (?, ?, ?)
...         ''', (
...             uuid.UUID('7005d0e0-f25b-45f9-897d-bae151fddaff'), 'user',
...             'user@gmail.com'
...         ))
...
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x107406570>
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> for row in cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM user'):
...     print(row)
...
(UUID('7005d0e0-f25b-45f9-897d-bae151fddaff'), 'user', 'user@gmail.com')
```

In the above demo, passing in a `uuid.UUID()` instance to `cursor.execute()` triggers the adapter registered with `register_adapter`, producing a bytestring to insert into the database column.

And when iterating over rows from a `SELECT`, the `sqlite3` library mapped the `GUID` type from the `user_id` column in the table schema and used the `register_converter()` registration of the same name to produce a `uuid.UUID()` instance from the bytes stored.

Answer (score 3):

`uuid.UUID` is not an SQL function, so you cannot use it in the SQL query.

You have to use a parameter so that Python can convert it:

```
cur.execute("INSERT ... VALUES (?,?,?)",
            (uuid.UUID('7005d0e0-f25b-45f9-897d-bae151fddaff'), 'user', 'user@gmail.com'))
```

Comment: This will insert the string representation of the UUID instance, which is quite far removed from the little-endian byte order they seem to want to support.